# Java Generics: getting return type from parameter

Tags: java, generics

This is an odd question. I don't *think* there's a solution, but I thought I'd ask anyway.

Say I have an enum:

```java
public enum Key {
    RED(String.class),
    GREEN(Integer.class),
    BLUE(Short.class);

    private Class<?> expectedType;

    Key(Class<?> expectedType) { this.expectedType = expectedType; }
    public Class<?> getExpectedType() { return expectedType; }
}
```

I want to use the '`expectedType`' field from the `Key` enum as the return type of a method. See:

```java
public class Cache {

    private static Map<Key, Object> cache = new HashMap<>();

    public void put(Key key, Object value) {
        // Easy to validate that 'value' is of type key.getExpectedType()...
    } 

    public <T> T get(Key key) {
        Object value = cache.get(key);
        // TODO need to define <T> as key.getExpectedType(). How?
        
    }
}
```

See that TODO? I'd like for `get()` to define the return type of the 'expectedType' defined by the `key` parameter. E.g. if the `key` parameter were `RED`, the `get()` method would return a String and you could write:

```java
    String s = cache.get(Key.RED);
```

Is there a way to do that?
I'm thinking there isn't, but I'd love to hear of a clever solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enums don't support generics, but you could use a regular class as a generic pseudo-enum:

```
public class Key<T> {
    public static final Key<String> RED = new Key<>(String.class);
    public static final Key<Integer> GREEN = new Key<>(Integer.class);
    public static final Key<Short> BLUE = new Key<>(Short.class);

    private final Class<T> expectedType;

    private Key(Class<T> expectedType) { this.expectedType = expectedType; }
    public Class<T> getExpectedType() { return expectedType; }
}

public class Cache {

    private Map<Key<?>, Object> cache = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> void put(Key<T> key, T value) {
        cache.put(key, key.getExpectedType().cast(value));
    } 

    public <T> T get(Key<T> key) {
        return key.getExpectedType().cast(cache.get(key));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the reason to apply `cast()` in the `put()`, why can't we simply store the offered value?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Not strictly necessary, but it prevents heap pollution in case it's used with a raw key, e.g. `cache.put((Key)Key.BLUE, "uh oh")`.

Comment: Thanks @shmosel! I didn't even consider not using an enum. 
This is perfect. Implemented your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

[shmosel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73627694/3788176) is almost certainly sufficient for what you need; however, it has the slight limitation that you can't store/retrieve a generic type, because you can't get a class literal for a generic type.

Instead, you can use something like [Guava's `TypeCapture`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/reflect/TypeCapture.java):

```
abstract class GenericKey<T> {
  Type getExpectedType() {
    return ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
        .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
  }
}
```

which is a bit of reflective grossness that you shouldn't spend too much time looking at.

Notice that it's abstract, so you have to instantiate like:

```
new GenericKey<Integer>() {}
```

This is creating an anonymous subclass of `GenericKey`, which is part of the magic that makes it work with generic types.

Then, it's basically the same:

```
public class Cache {

    private Map<GenericKey<?>, Object> cache = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> void put(GenericKey<T> key, T value) {
        cache.put(key.getExpectedType(), value);
    } 

    public <T> T get(GenericKey<T> key) {
        return (T) cache.get(key.getExpectedType());
    }
}
```

Now you could have a `GenericKey<List<Integer>>`, using `new  new GenericKey<List<Integer>() {}`, if you should so desire.

The downside of this approach is that you lose the ability to do checking on the value on the way in/out of the cache, so you could get heap pollution if you are careless with raw types.

Comment: And for reference, this concept is generally called 'super type tokens', in case you want to search the web for examples of how this is used and more in depth tutorials. It's a worthwhile thing to keep in mind here, good addition. Wish there was a way to vote to combine answers ;)